# Nextjs 14 app router, page.js & route.js in same path for initial data loading

Tags: next.js13

In Nextjs 14 app router, can we have page.js & route.js in same path? how to call the route API from the page? When the path is used, nextjs uses page.js for rendering. If i want to call an API with the same path from within the page, is it possible to write a route.js file in the same directory?

The idea behind this question is to use this route to load initial data through a custom hook 'useLoaderData' which calls this api using useEffect.